# Error on getting notification count in Asynctask

Tags: android

This is my Main Activity `AsyncTask`.

```
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        int i;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); //Here I get an error: The constructor ProgressDialog(PFragment) is undefined
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            pDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

          //  emailid = args[0];
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {


                        user1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", loginemail));
                        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(userprofile, "GET", params);

//                        String HT ;

                        // HT= "5004";
                        // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailid));
                        // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAGu_id, deviceId));
                        //  JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(userprofile, "GET", params);


                        //    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_rs", HT));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        //   JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        //          userprofile, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
//                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_success);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_USER); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
                            unread = product.getString("unread_notes");
                            unread = "105";
//                            tv.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(unread)));
                            //Log.d("Single company Details", json.toString());
                            // Log.d("BAgersssssssssss", String.valueOf(unread));
                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            // cm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T1);
                            // cc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T2);
                            //  na = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T3);
                            //  em = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T4);
                            //ph = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T5);
                            //dte = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.T9);
//                            cm = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.T1);
//                            cc = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.T2);
//                            na = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.T3);
//                            em = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.T4);
//                            ph = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.T5);
//                            dte = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.T9);
//                            cm = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.T1);
//                            cc = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.T2);
//                            na = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.T3);
//                            em = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.T4);
//                            ph = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.T5);
//                            dte = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.T9);
//                            as =(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.T10);
                            //txtPrayBody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrayRequest);
                            /*
                            txtPrayFrom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtYourName);
                            txtPrayerMade = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_num_prayers);
                            */

                            // display product data in EditText

//                            cm.setText(product.getString(TAG_company_name));
//                            cc.setText(product.getString(TAG_customer_code));
//                            na.setText(product.getString(TAG_name));
//                            em.setText(product.getString(TAG_email));
//                            ph.setText(product.getString(TAG_phoneno));
//                            dte.setText(product.getString(TAG_date));
//                            as.setText(product.getString(TAG_associated_since));
                            /*
                            txtPrayBody.setText(product.getString(TAG_BODY));
                            txtPrayFrom.setText(product.getString(TAG_FOOTER));
                            txtPrayerMade.setText(product.getString(TAG_NUM_PRAYERS));
                            */
                            // unread = "2";
                           // i= Integer.valueOf(unread);
                        //  i = Integer.parseInt(unread);
                            Log.d("i", String.valueOf(unread));

                            //int compare = Integer.parseInt(unread);
                            if(i == 0)
                            {
//                                 tv.setText(" ");
                               tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }else
                            if(i >= 99){
                                tv.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt("99+")));
                                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            else {
                                tv.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(unread)));
                                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        } else {
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                //    });


            });
            return loginemail;
        }
```

This option menu in Main Activty.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.againex, menu);
        RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.getItem(R.id.Notification).getActionView();
        ImageView img=(ImageView)badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.click);
        tv = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
//        tv.setText(String.valueOf(unread));
//unread
        //tv.setText("0");
//tv.setText(unread);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent nf =new Intent(MainActivity.this,Notifylist.class);
                startActivity(nf);
                //  tv.setText(" ");
             // int  i = Integer.parseInt(unread);
                // Log.d("i", String.valueOf(unread));
                //int compare = Integer.parseInt(unread);
//                            if(i == 0)
//                            {
//                              //  tv.setText("0");
//                                tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                            }else
//                            if(i >= 99){
//                                tv.setText("99+");
//                                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                            }
//                            else {
//                                tv.setText(unread);
//                                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                            }
                tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                new ChangeNotification().execute();
            }

        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
//    case R.id.Notification:
//Intent nf =new Intent(Review_List.this,Notifylist.class);
//startActivity(nf);
//           return true;
            //  case R.id.User_Profile:
//          Intent wr1 =new Intent(Review_List.this,UserProfile.class);
//          wr1.putExtra("Tag_emailid",loginemail);
//          //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+loginemail,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//          startActivity(wr1);
            //return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I used layout in `OptionMenu` with notification bell and with help of `AsyncTask` I used this to bring value of unread count. But getting  `NullPointerException` in count settext i.e (tv.settext();).

Error Log

```
11-26 17:13:01.300  30644-30644/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-26 17:13:01.950  30644-30668/samples.exoguru.materialtabs I/GMPM﹕ App measurement is starting up
11-26 17:13:02.030  30644-30668/samples.exoguru.materialtabs E/GMPM﹕ getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
11-26 17:13:02.070  30644-30668/samples.exoguru.materialtabs E/GMPM﹕ Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
11-26 17:13:02.110  30644-30647/samples.exoguru.materialtabs W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 20ms
11-26 17:13:02.160  30644-30654/samples.exoguru.materialtabs I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 363(47KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 1051KB/2MB, paused 0 total 130ms
11-26 17:13:02.510  30644-30644/samples.exoguru.materialtabs D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
11-26 17:13:02.550  30644-30675/samples.exoguru.materialtabs D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f507ec32840, tid 30675
11-26 17:13:02.560  30644-30675/samples.exoguru.materialtabs I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-26 17:13:03.100  30644-30675/samples.exoguru.materialtabs D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
11-26 17:13:03.110  30644-30675/samples.exoguru.materialtabs W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-26 17:13:03.110  30644-30675/samples.exoguru.materialtabs W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f507f1e9880, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-26 17:13:03.140  30644-30644/samples.exoguru.materialtabs I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-26 17:13:05.250  30644-30675/samples.exoguru.materialtabs W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-26 17:13:05.250  30644-30675/samples.exoguru.materialtabs W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f507f1e9a40, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-26 17:13:05.320  30644-30644/samples.exoguru.materialtabs D/sqlite Details:﹕ Id: 1 ,Name:  ,Email: karan.taneja@amartam.com,Phone no:,device id:null,Reg id:1,reg date:2015-11-13 07:24:15,flag:2
11-26 17:13:05.370  30644-30644/samples.exoguru.materialtabs D/sqlite Details:﹕ Id: 1 ,Name:  ,Email: karan.taneja@amartam.com,Phone no:,device id:null,Reg id:1,reg date:2015-11-13 07:24:15,flag:2
11-26 17:13:05.490  30644-30675/samples.exoguru.materialtabs W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-26 17:13:05.490  30644-30675/samples.exoguru.materialtabs W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f507f1e9ac0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
11-26 17:13:05.990  30644-30644/samples.exoguru.materialtabs D/i﹕ 105
11-26 17:13:05.990  30644-30644/samples.exoguru.materialtabs D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
11-26 17:13:05.990  30644-30644/samples.exoguru.materialtabs E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: samples.exoguru.materialtabs, PID: 30644
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
            at samples.exoguru.materialtabs.MainActivity$GetProductDetails$1.run(MainActivity.java:312)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Post your error log.

Comment: I Add the Eror Log Please see and help me.

Comment: @Frank N.Stein. please send meyour answer link.Please help me.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference` Debug your code to find which **null** object you are referencing (hint: it's a TextView).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I use this 
 
tv.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(unread)));

Comment: Please tell me any suggestion.

Comment: @Frank N.Stein on which point u saying my tv is null please see and help me to identify. Please hrlp me

Comment: See @MustanserIqbal answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot interact with UI while you are in background... its only possible that you display any message on UI in PostExecute() or in onProgressUpdate().

Comment: If I put these condition on postexecute() also it giving same error in logcat.

Comment: your "tv" is null recheck it...

Comment: tv.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(unread)));

Comment: see this textview I used in Textview.